# Locate specific table row based on text string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, find, capybara, rspec2

I am working with RSpec and Capybara and have encountered a problem while trying to select a specific row based on :textContent or :text attributes but regardless of the string entered in the test the first row is always selected.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<table class="LearningAssetList admin" data-id="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="CategoryHeader">
      <td class="expandCell" colspan="9">
        <span>Admin Pro / Scheduling</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="headerRow ui-droppable">
      <td class="blank"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Description</td>
      <td class="center">Length</td>
      <td class="center">User Rating</td>
      <td style="width:20px;padding:0px;"></td>
      <td style="width:20px;padding:0px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assetRow ui-draggable ui-droppable" data-id="49">
      <td class="blank">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="assetPlay icon">
      <td class="assetName">
        <a onclick="openModal('http://www.youtube.com/v/C0DPdy98e4c','Learning Asset    
Test Upload')" href="#">Learning Asset Test Upload</a>
      </td>
      <td class="assetDescription">
      <td class="assetDuration">
      <td class="assetRating icon">
      <td class="assetFunctions center">
      <td class="assetDrag center">
      <td class="blank">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My RSpec code is as follows:

```
it "should allow asset to be deleted by Admins" do
visit 'http://localhost:3000/'  
click_link 'Admin'  
within(:xpath, '//*[@class="LearningAssetList admin"]') do
  #row = find('tr>td.assetName>a', :textContent => "Learning Asset Test Upload")
  row = find('tr>td.assetName>a', :textContent => "Learning Asset Test Upload".to_s)
  within(row) do
    find(:xpath, '//*[@class="popupMenu"]').click       
  end   
  sleep 5
  find(:xpath, '//*[@class="delete"]').click

  popup = page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert
  popup.text.should eq('Are you sure you would like to delete this asset?')
  popup.accept        
  assetList = find(:xpath, '//*[@class="LearningAssetList admin"]')
  assetList.should have_content('Learning Asset Test Upload')
  sleep 5     
end
```

end

I have another row in the table above this entry where the assetName is simply "Test" and regardless of whether I use text, textContext, or indeed change the string this row is always selected and the more options button is pressed in this row which subsequently ends up in the deletion of the wrong asset.

Can anyone see any problem with the RSpec code or the logic behind selecting the row, I had thought that the text in the assetName td would have to match for the row to be found but this does not seem to be happening.

Comment: There are many things you could do to improve the test and narrow down the error. XPath syntax is of no benefit here and is likely to lead to errors, use things like `within(".LearningAssetList.admin")`. `:textContent` is not a known attribute in the Capybara documentation AFAIK.
The `:text` option may be doing a partial match, try renaming the row completely.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is completely invalid. You can't nest multiple `<tr>`s inside each other and you haven't closed any of the tags.

Comment: Hey Andrew it wasnt expanded properly can you please have another look to see if you can see the problem, thanks